# VSTS : Need list of users assigned to the story for their task

Tags: azure-devops, agile, scrum

I have number of user-stories for my project. For each user story I have around 5 to 6 child task and each is assign to different people like  PM, developer, QA etc.

Fetching user story and task wise user is easy.
But I want to fetch story and list of users associated with its child task.
Can you please guide me on this.

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve the problem?

Comment: I have installed a Team plugin in excel. Using it i am able to access query result in excel. using it I can prepare any kinf of data I need. But I am not able to create a query which gives me parent id of the task or any link id.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think query can meet your need. You should change the Type of query to Work items and direct links.
[image]

And then set the filters as follow.
[image]

You can get all child task and the User story which associated with child task. And in the Assigned To column, you can get the users assigned to the task.
[image]

Also you can use REST API to get the work items id. 
Post https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1 and input the follow WIQL in request body.

```
SELECT
    [System.Id],
    [System.WorkItemType],
    [System.Title],
    [System.AssignedTo],
    [System.State],
    [System.Tags]
FROM workitemLinks
WHERE
    (
        [Source].[System.TeamProject] = @project
        AND [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story'
    )
    AND (
        [System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward'
    )
    AND (
        [Target].[System.TeamProject] = @project
        AND [Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'
    )
ORDER BY [System.Id]
MODE (MustContain)
```

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: 'https://dev.azure.com/ABC/XYZ/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1',
   type: 'POST',
   data: JSON.stringify( '{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task' AND [State] <> 'Closed' AND [State] <> 'Removed' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}'),
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("" + ":" + 'xxxx')
            }
        }).done(function( results ) {
         
        });

Comment: Hi, Frank, I am using now jquery to access rest API, I am able to access other methods, but for the query it is giving errors, can you please guide here